# BIND round-robin doesn't work as expected

Tags: linux, networking, dns, unix, bind

I'm building round-robin DNS with BIND 9. 
I thought I made it cause when I type `nslookup stack.gearon.com`, several ip returned like:

```
Server:         10.1.2.210
Address:        10.1.2.210#53

Name:   stack.gearon.com
Address: 10.1.2.213
Name:   stack.gearon.com
Address: 10.1.2.210
Name:   stack.gearon.com
Address: 10.1.2.212
```

However, when I ping `stack.gearon.com`, the IP returned is always the same on that node.
Let me clarify it with an example. Assume I have 5 nodes A, B, C, D and E. The machine C, D and E are servers, if I ping `stack.gearon.com` on those server machines, their own ip will be returned and always the same. If I ping `stack.gearon.com` from client machine A or B, the IP returned is one of server's IP but also fixed.

My configurations is like below.

## /etc/resolve.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 10.0.2.210
```

## /etc/named.conf

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 { any; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query     { any; };

        /*
         - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
         - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable
           recursion.
         - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access
           control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
           cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification
           attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
           reduce such attack surface
        */
        recursion no;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

zone "stack.com" IN {
  type master;
  file "stack.com.db";
  allow-update{none;};
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

## /var/named/stack.com.db

```
$TTL 1D
@ IN SOA primary.gearon.com. root.stack.com.(
;2014112511 ;Serial
0 ;Serial
1D ;Refresh
1H ;Retry
1W ;Expire
3H ;Minimum TTL
)
;; 1st DNS
@ IN    NS      primary.gearon.com.
        A       10.1.2.210
;; Host List
primary         IN A 10.1.2.210
;; Enable round-robin here
stack           IN A 10.1.2.210
                IN A 10.1.2.212
                IN A 10.1.2.213
```

Please let me know if you need more details and thanks for your help in advance. Any comment is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs in to the same issue. 
I solved the issue by restart network with `ifdown` and `ifup` to flush the `ARP` table.